# como hacer un consultar php js

Tags: php, javascript, php7

tengo una caja de texto  ...

```html
       <h3>Tu correo electrónico</h3>
<input type="email" placeholder="tu@correo.com" class=""  id="usuariorecuperar" required />
 <input hidden type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row2['usuario_id'];  ?>" placeholder="" id="idusuario">
   
     <div class="contact-enviar">
      <button id="enviarContrasena">Recuperar</button>
 
</div>
```

quisiera que cuando en la caja de texto escriba el correo me traiga en la **hidden** el id de ese correo que se encuentra en la bd ...

```js
  $("#enviarContrasena").click(function() {

    var id=$("#idusuario").val();
    var usuariorecuperar=$("#usuariorecuperar").val();

    if((usuariorecuperar== "")) {

      swal("error", "ingrese un  correo en el campo", "error");
      
    }else{

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/functions/clave/claverespuesta.php",
        data:"usuariorecuperar="+usuariorecuperar+"&id="+id,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $("#recuperandoclave").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'>");
        },
        success: function(html){
          $("#recuperandoclave").html(html);
          $("#usuariorecuperar").val('');
         

        }

      });}
   });
```

```html
<?php 

sleep(1);
include('../../database/conexion.php');
$respuesta=  $_POST['usuariorecuperar'];
$id=  $_POST['id'];


$result = $bd->query ("SELECT * from usuario where usuario_id ='$id' and correo = '$respuesta' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
 $a= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo '<strong>Su correo es : </strong>' .$a['correo']; 
 echo '<strong>Su contraseña es : </strong>' .$a['contrasena']; 
?>
 <br><br>
 <?php
 echo '<strong>Esta mal';
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```
// Creamos el objeto con los datos
var data = {

  id: $("#idusuario").val(),
  usuariorecuperar: $("#usuariorecuperar").val()
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "includes/functions/clave/claverespuesta.php",

  data: data, // Aquí pasamos el objeto data 

  beforeSend: function(){    
    $("#recuperandoclave").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'>");
  }
}).done( function ( html ) {

  $("#recuperandoclave").html(html);
  $("#usuariorecuperar").val('');

}).fail(function(err) {

  // Aquí mostramos el mensaje de error
  console.log( 'Error: ' + err );
});
```

Aparte debes revisar tu código `PHP` en la consulta, es vulnerable a [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)